# Invalid column name when inserting in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here is my query, but when I execute it, I get an error and the column does not exist in my table `SLCCMN`.

Please help - what's the problem?

```
INSERT INTO [Sales Ledger Transactions] (STMN, STSLMN, STInvoiceNum)
VALUES ('16989632', '1', '1')
```

Error:

> Invalid column name 'SLCCMN'

Comment: Does the table have any triggers on it?

Comment: not really, any trigger

Comment: sorry, i found there is a triggers and the column name is specified in that.

Comment: so can you please tell me what is the solution, should i remove that trigger

Comment: you can either remove the trigger, or remove the reference to the SLCCMN column in the trigger's code.

Answer (score 4):

Check the table for triggers, and see if there is an invalid column reference in the trigger code.

Then either remove the trigger, or remove the reference to the SLCCMN column in the trigger's code.